# How to set up node socket connection and access with REST

Tags: angularjs, sockets, websocket, sails.js

I want to have a route on my sailsjs node server that is a socket connection. I want to then send a rest request to that route from outside the app and have the socket hear the event and update the UI of my app.

So far all I have seen on the web is to have a websocket server by itself. Is there no way to integrate it into an existing server?

I'm a bit lost here. Can anyone point me to a tutorial that is doing this?

Question: How do I send a rest request to my server from outside the app and have the server update the UI of my app?

If you need more clarity here, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Have to use WebSockets I think. The UI does not know anything about the server unless it is notified. The only other way to have it running without WebSockets is to have a long polling AJAX request, but that solution would work for a limited use cases.

Adding a Socket.io server to a node server is pretty trivial, I would give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Use socket.io, it can be added to every Node.js server. For example:

```js
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
  , fs = require('fs');

app.listen( 80 );

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.set('log level', 1);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

You can use any socket event here.